# Unable to clone via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, rhodecode

I found [this topic/thread](https://community.rhodecode.com/t/cloning-ssh-repositories-problem/192/5) but my issue is *not* RC being run by the wrong user. My SSH clone URL looks like this: `ssh://root@my.tld/another-test` and access is denied.

However, HTTP cloning works just fine.

My public keys are in my RC config file as well. Here is the content from `cat /var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jul 21 01:52:05 CODE sshd[21525]: Accepted publickey for root from [REDACTED] port 50481 ssh2: RSA SHA256:qwerty
Jul 21 01:52:05 CODE sshd[21525]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 21 01:52:05 CODE systemd-logind[847]: New session 1607 of user root.
Jul 21 01:52:06 CODE sshd[21525]: Received disconnect from [REDACTED] port 50481:11: disconnected by user
Jul 21 01:52:06 CODE sshd[21525]: Disconnected from user root [REDACTED] port 50481
Jul 21 01:52:06 CODE sshd[21525]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Jul 21 01:52:06 CODE systemd-logind[847]: Removed session 1607.
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

In `/root/.rccontrol/community-1/rhodecode.ini` I see this in the SSH section:

```
## AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys %h/.ssh/authorized_keys_rhodecode
ssh.authorized_keys_file_path = ~/.ssh/authorized_keys_rhodecode
```

I thought maybe I should be using `ssh.authorized_keys_file_path` or `AuthorizedKeysFile` but `rccontrol status` doesn't like that...

```sh
RHODECODE CONTROL VERSION: 1.23.0
Failed to parse /root/.rccontrol/community-1/rhodecode.ini
Invalid line ('AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys %h/.ssh/authorized_keys_rhodecode') (matched as neither section nor keyword) at line 589.
```

Output of `cat /root/.rccontrol/vcsserver-1/vcsserver.log`:

```
KeyError: 'HEAD'
2019-07-21 02:02:22.883 [1099] INFO  [vcsserver.tweens] IP: 127.0.0.1 Request to path: `/git` time: 0.005s
2019-07-21 02:02:22.887 [<1099>  ] GNCRN 127.0.0.1       rqt:0.009307 200 51     "POST:/git " usr:- "-" "PycURL/7.43.0.2 libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2p zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.24.0"
2019-07-21 02:02:50.693 [1099] DEBUG [vcsserver.http_main] method called:assert_correct_path with kwargs:{} context_uid: [REDACTED]
2019-07-21 02:02:50.693 [1099] DEBUG [dogpile.lock] NeedRegenerationException
2019-07-21 02:02:50.693 [1099] DEBUG [dogpile.lock] no value, waiting for create lock
2019-07-21 02:02:50.694 [1099] DEBUG [dogpile.lock] value creation lock <dogpile.cache.region._LockWrapper object at 0x7f42aeecd590> acquired
2019-07-21 02:02:50.694 [1099] DEBUG [dogpile.lock] Calling creation function for not-yet-present value
2019-07-21 02:02:50.694 [1099] DEBUG [dogpile.lock] Released creation lock
2019-07-21 02:02:50.695 [1099] INFO  [vcsserver.tweens] IP: 127.0.0.1 Request to path: `/git` time: 0.002s
2019-07-21 02:02:50.695 [<1099>  ] GNCRN 127.0.0.1       rqt:0.002517 200 51     "POST:/git " usr:- "-" "PycURL/7.43.0.2 libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2p zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.24.0"
2019-07-21 02:02:50.869 [1099] DEBUG [vcsserver.http_main] http-app: handling git stream
2019-07-21 02:02:50.869 [1099] DEBUG [vcsserver.http_main] LFS: Detecting if request `/another-test/info/refs` is LFS server path based on content type:``, is_lfs:False
2019-07-21 02:02:50.869 [1099] DEBUG [vcsserver.http_main] LFS: fallback detection by path of: `/another-test/info/refs`, is_lfs:False
2019-07-21 02:02:50.869 [1099] DEBUG [vcsserver.http_main] http-app: starting app handler with <vcsserver.scm_app.GitHandler object at 0x7f42aeecd590> and process request
2019-07-21 02:02:50.878 [1099] INFO  [vcsserver.tweens] IP: 127.0.0.1 Request to path: `/another-test/info/refs` time: 0.010s
2019-07-21 02:02:50.879 [<1099>  ] GNCRN 127.0.0.1       rqt:0.010726 200 38     "GET:/another-test/info/refs service=git-upload-pack" usr:- "-" "git/2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)"
```

EDIT: For the time being, I am using stored git credentials via `git config --global credential.helper store` (from my local machine) so I can clone my private repos. This is undesired though, SSH operations *should* work.

EDIT 2: I haven't gotten this nor RhodeCode tokens to work so git credentials it is. If I ever figure out the issue/solution I'll update here.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought maybe I should be using `ssh.authorized_keys_file_path`

You should make sure the public key is in `ssh.authorized_keys_file_path` file, that is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys_rhodecode`
No need to touch `rhodecode.ini` if you use `rccontrol enable-module ssh {instance-id}`, as [per the documentation](https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/auth/ssh-connection.html).

The issue is [more about LFS though](https://code.rhodecode.com/rhodecode-vcsserver/files/90644f979fa029551ff1daf50ed5ba123925519c/vcsserver/git_lfs/app.py#L110-111):

```
except KeyError:
    log.exception('LFS, failed to extract data')
```

Comment: SSH has already been enabled on my instance. Would this LFS error really be the reason I am unable to clone? I had the relevant options selected in the admin area already.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby Yes, I suspect the error LFS is relevant, but I don't know yet why or how it interferes with SSH cloning.

Comment: I turned LFS off in the settings, created a brand new repo and added commits via the web interface. Still, no dice. I'll keep looking around.